# ASP.NET MVC DropDownList value on HttpPost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel, html.dropdownlistfor

I am following this [Tutorial on ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc), specifically where it states that providing the String of `"MovieType"` to the Razor View as follows:`@Html.DropDownList("MovieType")` will provide the key to **DropDownList** to find a property in the `ViewBag` of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

That works just fine.

However, I am unable to get the value that the User selects on my method with `[HttpPost]` attribute.

Here is my code and what I have tried thus far.

**Controller**

```
public class ProductController : Controller 
{
    private readonly ProductRepository repository = new ProductRepository();

    // Get: /Product/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var categories = repository.FindAllCategories(false);
        var categorySelectListItems = from cat in categories
                                      select new SelectListItem()
                                          {
                                              Text = cat.CategoryName,
                                              Value = cat.Id.ToString()
                                          };
        ViewBag.ListItems = categorySelectListItems;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Product product)
    {
        /** The following line is not getting back the selected Category ID **/
        var selectedCategoryId = ViewBag.ListItems;
        repository.SaveProduct(product);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

**Razor cshtml View**

```
@model Store.Models.Product

<h2>Create a new Product</h2>

@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>Product Name:</p>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProductName)

    <p>Price</p>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Price)

    <p>Quantity</p>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Quantity)

    <p>Category</p>
    @Html.DropDownList("ListItems")
    <p><input type="submit" value="Create New Product"/></p>
}
```

I tried playing with the overloads for `DropDownList`, but I am not able to get the value back that the User is selecting.

If anyone sees what I am missing or has any ideas or suggestions, I would be very grateful.  Thanks!

**Update**

Posting `Product` Model.  Note, this was auto-generated by Entity Framework when I created the .edmx.

```
namespace Store.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Product
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> CategoryId { get; set; }

        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your Product object have a ListItems field?

Comment: @DaveA Nope.  However, in my first `Create()` method, I put it into the `ViewBag`.  I'm trying to figure out if there's a way I can separate the "getting" of the drop-down `SelectListItem` from the property that is sent back on the `[HttpPost]`.  I really don't need the `SelectListItems` to come back when the User posts, only the ID of what they selected.

Comment: ListItems is the variable you bound to. you need ListItems param or object containing as param to action method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing a model of type `Store.Models.Product` into your view.  The other fields are binding to this model using a lambda expression, but `@Html.DropDownList()` does not bind to the model so when the model is returned in the HTTPPost the selection is not there.

You need to add your `Category` field to `Store.Models.Product` and then bind to that list using:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Category, ViewBag.ListItems)
```

Then MVC should properly bind your input control to the model.

As an example, this syntax does work:

```
int[] listItems = {1, 2, 3, 4};
SelectList selectList = new SelectList(listItems);
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryId, selectList);
```

Note that [`SelectList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) inherits from [`MultiSelectList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.multiselectlist%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) which implements `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

Comment: This IS a better way. I wonder if it answers OP's question about specifically using the property-name-string approach and why it failed. (side point, you didn't cast the ViewBag")

Comment: +1 Thank you, you were correct in that I was not binding to the model, which led me in the right direction.  However, I ended up not being able to use the lambda expression you provided, not sure why it didn't work.  It did not like `m=> m.Category` (I also tried `m=> m.CategoryId`).  I ended up with something with ugly syntax that functioned correctly but is not elegant, please see my answer.

Comment: This worked, I am now able to use the more elegant syntax that you provided.  Answer accepted, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Follow what Peter G. has mentioned in his answer, but just for informational purposes, you should also be able to change your Post controller to this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Product product, int ListItems)
{

}
```

As Peter has mentioned (once again, use his answer), the problem is that when your form posts, your DropDown list has a name of "ListItems" and there is nothing on your controller for it to bind to.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following:

**Controller**

```
...
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Product product)
    {
        var categoryId = product.CategoryId;
        repository.SaveProduct(product);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
...
```

**Razor cshtml View**

```
...
<p>Category</p>
@Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewData["ListItems"])
...
```

It looks ugly and to be honest, I don't fully understand why I was not able to use a lambda expression like Peter suggested, `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryId, ViewBag.ListItems)`.

To me, I've "got it to work", but want to understand why, and if there is a more elegant way I can do it.

When I typed in `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryId, ViewBag.ListItems)`, IntelliSense would auto-fill `m.CategoryId`, but then would flag it in red, and I would get runtime error.

Comment: What does your `Product` model look like?

Comment: @PeterGluck I updated my original question to include it.  It is generated by EF.

Comment: @Philip, see the example in my answer.